# Specify Binding of DependencyProperty in UserControl itself

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls, dependencyobject

Following up on my previous question ([Change brushes based on ViewModel property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33042409/change-brushes-based-on-viewmodel-property))

In my UserControl I have have a `DependencyObject`. I want to bind that object to a property of my `ViewModel`. In this case a `CarViewModel`, property name is `Status` and returns an enum value.

```
public partial class CarView : UserControl
{
    public CarStatus Status
    {
        get { return (CarStatus)GetValue(CarStatusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CarStatusProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CarStatusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Status", typeof(CarStatus), typeof(CarView), new PropertyMetadata(OnStatusChanged));

    private static void OnStatusChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var control = (CarView)obj;
        control.LoadThemeResources((CarStatus)e.NewValue == CarStatus.Sold);
    }

    public void LoadThemeResources(bool isSold)
    {
        // change some brushes
    }
}


<UserControl x:Class="MySolution.Views.CarView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:views="clr-MySolution.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             views:CarView.Status="{Binding Status}">   
    <UserControl.Resources>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Brand}"FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
<UserControl
```

Where do I need to specify this binding? In the root of the UserControl it gives an error:

> The attachable property 'Status' was not found in type 'CarView'

In my MainWindow I bind the CarView using a `ContentControl`:

```
<ContentControl
    Content="{Binding CurrentCar}">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:CarViewModel}">
            <views:CarView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

My ViewModel:

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class CarViewModel
{
    public Car Car { get; private set; }

    public CarStatus Status
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sold) return CarStatus.Sold;
            return CarStatus.NotSold;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am pretty at ease with MVVM, but I don't see what you re doing with the ContentControl. Inside the ContentControl there is a DataTemplate working only for CarView (DataType attribute is for selection not instanciation), and the binding with the CurrentCar property should have a DataContext object - that I still don't know how it is provided. If you want to provide your ViewModel with XAML : <Window.DataContext><viewmodel:CarViewModel/></Window.DataContext>. But I prefer to do it in C# : shorter and sometimes you have to  handle the VM in CS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your binding isn't well written. instead of writing `views:CarView.Status="{Binding Status}"` you should write only `Status="{Binding Status}"`

Comment: If I do that I get a different errors: "The property 'Status' was not found in type 'UserControl'" and the error: "The property 'Status' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'."

Comment: a thing you can do is to inherit from userControl. then define your depency property is your newly defined class. then instead of using an opening <Usercontrol> tag when defining your control, you'll use a new tag instance of your carView  someething like this <views:CarView> then the Status property will be available

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your Control is binding to itself.
Status is looked for in CarView.

You should have a line of code in your control CodeBehind like  :

```
this.DataContext = new ViewModelObjectWithStatusPropertyToBindFrom();
```

Regards

Comment: I've updated my question, I'm not setting the DataContext in code. I set it in XAML.

Comment: Fine, may be you should have shown the code. Does your DataContext object have a Status property ? According to your error message, it really seems the DataContext is the userControl. If you follow MVVM, the DataContext should be a VM object

Comment: CurrentCar is an object from type CarViewModel

Comment: A user/custom control should not need to set **it's own** `DataContext`. It is the responsibility of the control that **hosts** the control to set the `DataContext`. Otherwise you're control is tied to a specific view model implementation, whereas this should not be the case.

Comment: Yes you re right Mike. I meant, I prefer to provide the data through C# than XAML